# Degraded image: Wiener Filter vs Wiener deconvolution

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, blur

I am studying methods for recovering images (that has been blurred and noised).

Can someone explain the difference between:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter

I can understand that wiener deconvolution is used for `Deblurring` while wiener filter is used for `Denoising`.

Is that right? Are there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wiener deconvolution is an approach to solve the deconvolution problem that relies on the filter proposed by Wiener. The equation is the **same** in denoising and deblurring, except that the filter $G$ (to stick with Wikipedia's notations) that you should use is different.

To make things clear:

- denoising consists in the case where the degradation kernel $H$ is the identity,
- in deconvolution this kernel is equal to the blur kernel that destroyed your image (motion 
  blur, lens PSF...).

Hence, in denoising, the $H$ part that appears in the expression of the Wiener filter $G$ disappears (it is equal to 1), while in deconvolution it is equal to the Fourier transform of your blur kernel.

More generally, when using an inverse problem approach for these tasks, i.e. solving $\| A x - y \|^2 + \lambda g(x)$ (with $x$ your solution and $y$ the noisy observation, $g(x)$ some prior on $x$), you can always switch between denoising and deconvolution by choosing $A = Id$.